# Jenkins job on AWS server

Tags: api, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ant, jmeter

I have a windows instance set up on AWS. I have Jmeter and Ant installed on that machine to run API test cases.So I can successfully run tests on remote server. I need to set up a job on corporate Jenkins to run those test cases on aws server. I have server's IP address and username and password to log in to aws server.
How do I set up a job on corporate Jenkins which will run my test cases on remoter aws server? (Execute windows command)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

did you connect this AWS machine as a slave to the master ? or you can't do it ?

I think that the best is connect this machine as a slave and create a dedicated job to run on the windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a new Ant task to run JMeter test in Jenkins is fairly easy, here is a simple [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) script which executes Ant task using `build.xml` file in the "extras" folder of JMeter installation and publishes resulting HTML report on the build artifacts page:

```
node {
   ws('c:\\jmeter\\extras') {
       stage 'Run JMeter Test with Apache Ant'
       def antHome = tool 'ant'
       bat "pushd c:\\jmeter\\extras && ${antHome}\\bin\\ant -f build.xml"
       step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'Test.html', fingerprint: true])
   }
}
```

You will need to [define `ant` tool](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s06.html) so Jenkins would know what is "ant" and where it lives. See [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial) article for details.

Alternative options are:

- If you have Jenkins admin access or your user has "Job - Configure" role you have "Configure" button where you can see (and change) all the build steps

  [image: Jenkins Configure Project]
- You can copy the whole Jenkins installation over to your corporate intranet (don't forget [JENKINS_HOME](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) folder)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your response. I have set it my windows AWS machine as Slave. And I was able to run the job on AWS server from corporate jenkins.